# Sudo as another user to save their home directory address to a txt file

Tags: scripting, sudo, users

I am trying to save a users home directory to a users.txt file, but I just keep saving my own. The script asks the user to enter their username, which I have saved in $username. When I run

```
ls ~ >> users.txt
```

It shows `ls home/student/am1014` (which is my username)

I assume I need to use sudo to store it but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can get the home directory of user from /etc/passwd file

Comment: What do you want to save exactly? The name of the home directory or the list of files and directories it contains? Why is sudo relevant? What script asks for username? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
sudo -u joe ls ~
```

`~` is expanded by your shell before running the command (here `sudo`), so in effect that runs:

```
sudo -u joe ls /home/me
```

To list the content of `joe`'s home directory:

```
ls ~joe
```

Or if you don't have read access to his home directory:

```
sudo -u joe ls ~joe
```

Or for a shell running *as `joe`* to expand the `~`:

```
sudo -u joe sh -c 'ls ~'
```

Note that except in `csh`/`tcsh`/`zsh` you can't use the `ls ~joe` approach if the name of the user is in a variable. Depending on the shell

```
user=joe
echo ~$user
```

would either output `/home/mejoe` or `~joe`. In `bash`, if there was a user called `$user` (literally), that would return his home directory.

Here you'd need:

```
eval "ls ~$user"
```

(you'd have made sure `$user` contains a valid user name beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

The following command will read `/etc/passwd` and will output `username : home-dir`

```
awk -F: '{print $1":" $6}' /etc/passwd
```

Output will be something like:

```
root:/root
daemon:/usr/sbin
bin:/bin
sys:/dev
sync:/bin
games:/usr/games
```

You can redirect the output to a file using:

```
awk -F: '{print $1":" $6}' /etc/passwd > result.txt
```

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is just one of the different possible backends where the user database may be stored. See also NIS+, LDAP, mysql... On some systems, you can use `getent passwd`. But here, you can just use `~user` to get the home directory of a given `user`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks :) I'm aware of ~username. Since the OP ask for *users*, having a one line solution which provide a list of all users in the system and their directory seems the best approach.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas for NIS+ running `ypcat passwd | awk -F: '{print $1":" $6}' ` should result with the same output